# How can I do a simple effect system with inheritance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I'm trying to practice with inheritance and just in general having scripts interact with each other and I thought doing a simple effect system could be fun, but I'm a bit stuck on how to structure things.

I keep wanting to do this

```
public abstract class BaseEffect : ScriptableObject
{
    //not sure if this is a good use of enum
    public enum EffectType 
    {
        harm, //can be applied to enemies
        help, //can be applied to allies
        self //can be applied to yourself
    }

    public string name;
    public string description;
    public float duration;
    public bool canStack; //can the effect be applied multiple times
    public EffectType type;

    //I'd probably also write my apply and remove effect methods here
}
```

And then a bunch of derived classes like this

```
public class TestEffect : BaseEffect
{
    //maybe include some variables specific to this effect  

    //when the effect gets applied have this run every frame to od whatever the effect does
    public void DoEffect()
    {

    }
}
```

I have a feeling though that this isn't a good way to go about doing this or at least the way I've written it isn't good so looking for some advice to get on the right track

Answer (score 0):

This arrangement may benefit from an abstract method or usage of an Interface consumed by an abstract class to enforce derived classes to respond to events. Speaking of events, you could also wire the derived calls up through events. In simple terms, introduce an abstract method in the base class, which must be implemented in derived classes. Then call the method in the base classes "plumbing" when everything special about the event is ready.

```
public abstract class BaseEffect : ScriptableObject
{
    protected abstract void DoEffect();
    
    private SomeMethod()
    {
       if(canDoEffect)
         DoEffect();
    }
}
```